# Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: c++, .net-4.0, 64-bit

I have a .Net 4.0 C++ application that used to be built in 32bits. Obviously when running on a 64bits station I was having issues, therefore I started rebuilding everything in 64 bits. The whole project is converted as well as the libraries I had made for this in other project files. All references have been updated and everything compiles fine.

Once deployed to a 64bit station I now get the following errors in the windows event viewer:

Information : Windows Error Reporting

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: EDI.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 4e32e547
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.1.7601.17625
P6: 4de88429
P7: e0434352
P8: 000000000000cacd
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_EDI.exe_b14cfebcf86ccaf91a35dacab06a28cdf7277ba_17f14701

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c9983227-ba04-11e0-9299-002713d66c71
Report Status: 0
```

Error : Application Error

```
Faulting application name: EDI.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4e32e547
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17625, time stamp: 0x4de88429
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000cacd
Faulting process id: 0x1704
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc4e118bde9f1d
Faulting application path: C:\Users\developer\Desktop\EDI_6.1.0.4160_x64\EDI_6.1.0.4160_x64\EDI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: c9983227-ba04-11e0-9299-002713d66c71
```

Error : .Net Runtime

```
Application: EDI.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at <Module>.main(System.String[])
```

When I run dependency walker on the executable, I get to see the executable listed in the modules and nothing else at all comes up.  I am kind of out of ideas at the moment and wondering if anyone can make something of this?

Comment: Are you using a debug build? It may provide more information in the stack trace.

Comment: It is a CLR exception, you cannot use DependencyWalker to analyze .NET dependencies.  Use fuslogvw.exe instead.  In general, ensure that .NET 4.0 is deployed on that machine, only deploy the Release build and ensure that you've deployed the CRT libraries.  Easy to do with a Setup and Deployment project.

Answer (score 0):

Exception code: `0xe0434352` 
Not very common. Check this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/pex/thread/b9728c2d-130e-48f9-80c1-442ddbc1e85b

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this same error-code, also in Kernelbase.dll when attempting to debug a C++ application in VS2012.  Fortunately in my case I tracked the issue down to the Document Well (from Productivity Powertools Extension) option:

Environment-Tabs and Windows-Maintain pin status if document is removed from well.

Clearing this option fixed my problem.  It appears that DevStudio was crashing when rearranging the tabs/windows for debugging.

This may not be the cause of your particular issue, but I've added it here because if anyone else searches for error code: 0xe0434352 in Kernelbase.dll, this issue is at the top of the Google search.